How does 'passive robust wireless power transfer' (wireless power unaffected by distance or orientation over a wide range) work?
This 2018 article and video from the University of Michigan talks about a passive method for wireless power transfer that is unaffected by distance and orientation over a wide range.
How do such methods work? What is the fundamental idea?

It's likely a simplification of language, used for popularisation. You won't get radiation without supplying energy, so "passive" is obviously used within a given context. Physics will physics, so there is energy falloff as a function of distance, but it might be a function with a low dfield/ddistance-section, and full circular symmetry

It looks like they're doing something with the driving waveform to maintain coupling through distance and orientation changes. You can see from their results that the performance is very good up to a point and then completely disappears. "Passive" in this case refers to the lack of feedback, I assume.

Photo from Semantic Scholar: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Exploiting-Nonlinearity-to-Design-Robust-Wireless-Abdelatty-Wang/9caed643bb9b9b14eefb0e96d2d2d3435fc10eda

The figure says that this technique maintains a high efficiency for close coupling at the price of an abrupt drop in power transfer at a critical value of the range. An interesting result, yielding a journal article good for the resume. As far as I can tell not world-changing.
